# transformar string em array Multidimensional

Tags: php, string, array-multidimensional

Eu tenho a string a baixo e já tentei transformar ela em um array Multidimensional mas não sei como se faz, outro problema que eu não consigo resolver são os espaços, mesmo usando um explode eles permanecem no array. qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.

O array multidimensional que eu quero é esse:

```
Array(2) ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 12/ 8/2008 [1] => 0 [2] => maria [3] =>  online) [1] => Array ([0] => 13/ 5/2013 [1] => 0 [2] => joão [3] => off));
```

Meu codigo.

```
$string = "0/ 0/0  0  maria online 0/ 0/0  0  joão off"; 

$ar = explode(" ", $string);

print_r($ar);
```

Comment: Se você conhece a função explode, e provavelmente conhece as estruturas de repetição, acho que tem que trabalhar a lógica de programação agora!

Comment: Uma dúvida a data você acrescenta como? Ou a data já vem na string?  O comando ```trim($variavel)``` remove os espaços no início e final da variável. Porque se você tem estes dados separados e agrupa, se ficar tipo ```$string = "0/0/00  maria online 0/0/00  joão off"; ``` fica melhor para depois separar certinho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que tem um jeito melhor, mas não consegui pensar direito nesse jeito. mas acho o que eu fiz serve.

```
<?php

$string = "0/ 0/0  0  maria online 0/ 0/0  0  joão off"; 
$count = 0;
$ar = explode(" ", $string);
foreach ($ar as $ar) {
    if($ar != ""){
        if ($count <= 4) {
            $dbArray[0][] = $ar;
        }else{
            $dbArray[1][] = $ar;
        }
        $count++;
    }
}

/*
versão sem loopping ou condicionais
$dbArray = [
    0 => [
        0 => $ar[0].$ar[1],
        1  => $ar[3],
        2 => $ar[5],
        3 => $ar[6]
    ],
    1 => [
        0 => $ar[7].$ar[8],
        1  => $ar[10],
        2 => $ar[12],
        3 => $ar[13]
    ]
];
*/
var_dump($dbArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pela ajuda vinicius, com seu incentivo eu consegui fazer dessa forma.

```
 $string = "0/ 0/0  0  maria online 0/ 0/0  0  joão off"; 
 $explode = explode(" ", $string);
 foreach ($explode as $explode) {
 if($explode != ""){
        $dbArrayy[] = $explode; 
 }        
};

$result = array_chunk($dbArrayy, 5);

print_r($result); 


//resultado
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 0/ [1] => 0/0 [2] => 0 [3] => maria [4] => online ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 0/ [1] => 0/0 [2] => 0 [3] => joão [4] => off ) )
```

Comment: Blz, não conhecia `array_chunk()`